# Overflow of an unsigned char in C++

Tags: c++, casting, overflow

I found following code snippet here https://www.toptal.com/c-plus-plus/interview-questions with the question: **How many times will this loop execute? Explain your answer**

```
unsigned char half_limit = 150;

for (unsigned char i = 0; i < 2 * half_limit; ++i)
{
    // do something;
}
```

The answer is infinite.

> The expression 2 * half_limit will get promoted to an int (based on
>   C++ conversion rules) and will have a value of 300. However, since i
>   is an unsigned char, it is rerepsented by an 8-bit value which, after
>   reaching 255, will overflow (so it will go back to 0) and the loop
>   will therefore go on forever.

I guessed 45 times (300-255), because I remember that if you increment an unsigned integer counter, the counter will start at 0 again when it overflows. Okay, so it casts from an integer to an unsigned char, why its not 255 then?

Thank you

Comment: what did you not understand about the explanation? Hard to answer without repeating exatctly the same `2 * half_limit` is promoted to `int`, its value is `300` and `i` can never be `>300` because it is an `unsigned char`.

Comment: The answer is undefined behavior unless you can show that the loop's body has an observable effect. Infinite loop with no observable behavior are UB and can be optimized out entirely.

Comment: You said ```Okay, so it casts from an integer to an unsigned char, why its not 255 then?``` but just before you qoute ```The expression 2 * half_limit will get promoted to an int```

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux we don't know if `// do something;` has an observable behavior.

Comment: @Ayxan well, it's a comment so we know that it does nothing :) If there is something we don't know there in place of the comment, then the answer would be: We don't know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why its not 255 then?

Because 255 is less than 300. In next iteration, `i` will be 0 which is also less than 300. No number representable by 8 bit integer can reach 300.

---

Technically, the correct answer is that the number of iterations depends on the size of `unsigned char`. On a system that uses a 16 bit byte, there would be no problem.

Another issue with the answer is that "infinite" loops are not allowed in the language unless certain actions are taken within the loop - such as generating some output. So actually, the example program has undefined behaviour (assuming 8 bit byte). Quote from 
the standard:

> [intro.progress]
>
> The implementation may assume that any thread will eventually do one
>   of the following:
>
> - terminate,
> - make a call to a library I/O function,
> - perform an access through a volatile glvalue, or
> - perform a synchronization operation or an atomic operation.
>
> [ Note: This is intended to allow compiler transformations such as
>   removal of empty loops, even when termination cannot be proven. — end
>   note  ]

Answer (score 4):

Arithmetic on types smaller than `int` first promotes them to `int`. For that reason `2 * half_limit` is `300`. Assuming the largest value `unsigned char` can represent is `255`, all the values `i` can possibly have satisfy `i < 2 * half_limit`, thus this is an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
2 * half_limit
```

is the same as:

```
int(2) * int(half_limit)
```

half_limit gets promoted to an integer to do the multiplication, and the result of the expression is 300. Thus,

```
i < 2 * half_limit
```

becomes

```
i < int(300)
```

where i gets promoted to an int to do the actual comparison, but since i is an unsigned char, it can never be bigger than 255 (assuming our unsigned chars are 8 bits), so that comparison is effectively:

```
int(smaller than 256) < int(300)
```

which is, of course, always true.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc,char* argv[]){

    unsigned char half_limit = 150;

    for (unsigned char i = 0; i < 2 * half_limit; ++i)
    {
        printf("%.2X\n", i);
    }
}
```

compiled this code with mingw g++. gave me an infinite loop, printing the hexadecimel
value of i shows that it gets resets every time it overflows. And perhaps when it overflows it sets a flag .. 
Correct me if I'm wrong